# Show trailing icon after text input from user in TextField Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, kotlin-android

I am trying to:

1. make the `trailingIcon` of `TextField` composable visible only if the user enters some text other than white spaces.
2. Later when the user clicks the `trailingIcon` the text in the `TextField` should get cleared and the `trailingIcon` should disappear.
3. Again when the user enters a text other than space, the `trailingIcon` should appear and enable this text clearing feature.

and so on...

I tried searching for solutions to this problem but mostly they were focused on "visible `trailingIcons`" and not what I was trying to implement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Depending on text state you can specify `null` or actual view for `trailingIcon` parameter:

```kotlin
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val trailingIconView = @Composable {
    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            text = ""
        },
    ) {
        Icon(
            Icons.Default.Clear,
            contentDescription = "",
            tint = Color.Black
        )
    }
}
TextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = { text = it },
    trailingIcon = if (text.isNotBlank()) trailingIconView else null,
)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add a condition to make visible the `trailingIcon`.

Something like:

```
var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
val isVisible by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        text.isNotBlank()
    }
}

OutlinedTextField(
    value = text,
    onValueChange = {
        text = it
    },
    trailingIcon = {
        if (isVisible) {
            IconButton(
                onClick = { text = "" }
            ) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Clear,
                    contentDescription = "Clear"
                )
            }
        }
    }
)
```

[image]